# Android Json Arraylist to Server with Restful Web service

Tags: android, json

This is my Arraylist which I get from the previous fragment,

```
 listoftags = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data");
```

It works well. Now I have to send this with some parameters like below:

```
public void volleyJsonObjectRequest(final String SessionID , final String CustomerID, final String ServiceState , final String ServiceID, final String Address, final String PaymentMode, final String CustomerComments , final ArrayList Items){

    String  REQUEST_TAG = "volleyJsonObjectRequest";

    // POST parameters

    CustomRequest request = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // Toast.makeText(SignActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("response",""+response.toString());

          /*  String status =  response.optString("StatusMessage");
            String actionstatus = response.optString("ActionStatus");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(actionstatus.equals("Success"))
            {
               // Intent i = new Intent(SignActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
             //   startActivity(i);
              //  finish();
            }*/
            dismissProgress();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error."+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("response",""+error.toString());
            dismissProgress();
        }
    }) {
    /*    @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }*/

        public String getBodyContentType()
        {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(listoftags);

            params.put("SessionID", SessionID);
            params.put("CustomerID", CustomerID);
            params.put("ServiceState", ServiceState);
            params.put("ServiceID", ServiceID);
            params.put("Address", Address);
            params.put("PaymentMode",PaymentMode);
            params.put("CustomerComments",CustomerComments);

            params.put("Items",jsArray.toString());

            return params;
        }

    };
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                        .addToRequestQueue(request, REQUEST_TAG);

}
```

but it getting error to me I want to send it like 
// server side //

```
{

    "SessionID":"9lm5255sg0ti9",
    "CustomerID":"9",
    "ServiceState":"Karnataka",
    "ServiceID":"3",
    "Address":"sfaff",
    "PaymentMode":"cash",
    "CustomerComments":"this is fine",
    "Items":[
        {
            "ItemId":1,
            "Cost":6777,
            "Quantity":33333
        }
    ]

}
```

How can send arraylist, with other strings, as raw data using volley on server.

Comment: "but it getting error to me" what is the error?

Comment: params.put("Items",URLEncoder.encode(jsArray.toString(), "UTF-8"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//  try the request //

try {

- REQUEST QUEUE

  ```
      RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
      String URL = url;
      JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
      Iterator itr = listoftags.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext()){
          AddRowItem ad=(AddRowItem)itr.next();

          jsonObject.put("ItemId:",1);
          jsonObject.put("Cost:",ad.getPrices());
          jsonObject.put("Quantity:",ad.getQty());
         // Log.d("ItemId:",""+1+" "+"Cost:"+ad.getPrices()+" "+"Quantity:"+ad.getQty());
      }
           jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
  ```
- JSON VALUES PUT

  ```
          jsonBody.put("SessionID", "9kp0851kh6mk3");
          jsonBody.put("CustomerID", "9");
          jsonBody.put("ServiceState", "Karnataka");
          jsonBody.put("ServiceID", "3");
          jsonBody.put("Address", "Address Demo");
          jsonBody.put("PaymentMode", "cost");
          jsonBody.put("CustomerComments", "Android Volley Demo");
          jsonBody.put("Items", jsonArray);


      final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
      Log.d("string ---- >",""+requestBody);


      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(String response) {
              Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
              showToast("get value"+response.toString());
            try {

                  JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);


                  String action = jObj.get("ActionStatus").toString();
                  String status = jObj.getString("StatusMessage");
               {"ActionStatus":"Success","StatusMessage":"Order Created","RefIDName":"OrderID","RefIDValue":19}
                  showToast("get value"+action);

              }
              catch (JSONException e)
              {
                  showToast("get error"+e.toString());
                  Log.d("errorissue",""+e.toString());
              }


              dismissProgress();
          }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  ```

// error response //

```
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                showToast("get error"+error.toString());
                dismissProgress();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        dismissProgress();
    }
}
```

}

// THIS IS THE WAY ISSUE RESLOVED // 
THANKS EVERYONE ...

Answer (score 0):

JsonObjectRequest can be used to execute rest api using json as input.

```
JsonObject jobj = new JsonObject();
jobj.put("key","value");
jobj.put("key","value");
jobj.put("key","value");
jobj.put("key","value");  



JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(requestURL, jobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});

*Now add this request in request queue of volley.*
```

Here jobj is containing input parameters. It can contain even json array inside a JsonObject. Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Oh great , so will you bless me with an up vote or by accepting my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather then volley try retrofit. Make pojo model of your object you want to send, you can make that from pojo classes from https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org the send the whole object on restapi